# Whitelisting in Cordova (Android)

Tags: android, dns, cordova, whitelist

I'm having some real trouble in what should really be a trivial task. I'm doing an FileTransfer.download in a Cordova Android app but am seeing the following error in my log: Source URL is not in the whitelist. I did my homework and found out about whitelisting in the file res/xml/config.xml (I am using Cordova 2.4.0) and tried absolutely every combination  that I could think to.

I tried
        <access origin="the exact url of the file" />
I tried
        <access origin="*" />
I tried
        <access origin=".*" />

and a hundred other things

I even tried to FileTransfer.download google.com but I am getting the same whitelisting error. I even went so far as to remove all the access tags from the config file except for those mentioned above but still no luck. If anybody has any suggestions, it would be GREATLY appreciated.. I've been slamming my head against this one for like three hours now, haha.

Oh, and I'm using Cordova 2.4.0 building for Android 2.2+ if it matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using DroidGap, you need:

Config.init(this);

in the onCreate of your Activity. Otherwise, all whitelisting will fail. Just found this out after two hours of painful digging through source.